# How can I get element value by Id in Angular

Tags: angular, angularjs

I have to get value of element by Id, I need string value and by selecting state from dropdown list, API returning ID. Now, what I've to do?
My sample code:

ShippingDetails.html

```
<ion-item lines="none" style="--border-radius: 5px;">
                    <ion-label>State</ion-label>
                    <ion-select value="0" okText="OK" #S (ionChange)="onStateChange(S.value)" cancelText="Cancel"
                      [(ngModel)]="address.state" required interface="popover">
                      <ion-select-option value="0">Select State</ion-select-option>
                      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let item of deliveryStateList" value="{{item.statE_ID}}">{{ item.statE_NAME}}
                      </ion-select-option>
                    </ion-select>
                  </ion-item>
```

ShippingDetails.ts

```
  async getDeliveryStateList() {
    const payload = {
      countryId: 1
    };
    this.generalService.getStateList(payload).subscribe(async res => {
      let response = new ApiResponse();
      response = Object.assign(response, res);
      this.deliveryStateList = response.data;
    });
  }

  async getDeliveryCityListList(stateid) {
    const payload = {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:radix
      stateId: parseInt(stateid)
    };
    this.generalService.GetCityListbyState(payload).subscribe(async res => {
      let response = new ApiResponse();
      response = Object.assign(response, res);
      this.deliveryCityList = response.data;
    });
  }

  onStateChange(stateid) {
    this.getDeliveryCityListList(stateid);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using ionChange right. Try with:

```
(ionChange)="onStateChange($event)
```

And in ts change your method to:

```
onStateChange(event) {
    this.getDeliveryCityListList(event.detail.value);
}
```

If you want to make sure the getDeliveryCityListList will get called with a string and not a number, you can do:

```
this.getDeliveryCityListList(event.detail.value.toString());
```

or:

```
this.getDeliveryCityListList(event.detail.value + '');
```